# Rescatar el CodeName en VBA

Tags: excel, vba, visual

necesito rescatar el CodeName de las hojas de un libro en Excel, usando para ello el nombre de la etiqueta.

En la hoja Preliminares hay una lista de opciones asociadas a un formulario que el usuario debe completar. Según la opción que elige, los datos ingresados se deben ir a la hoja correspondiente. Y para eso quiero usar el CodeName de la hoja.

Específicamente estoy haciendo esto:

```
For Each n In Preliminares.Range("A2:A13")

If Inicio.Range("C4") = "n" Then

If Inicio.Range("C8") = "1" Then

    Inicio.Range("B9") = "Descripción 1"
    Inicio.Range("B10") = ""
    Inicio.Range("B11") = ""

    Sheets(n).CodeName.Range("A11") = Inicio.Range("C9")
```

En la última línea la referencia al CodeName no la reconoce.

Comment: `Worksheets(n)` ?

Comment: también tira error si uso Worksheets: fuera del intervalo.

Comment: Tu bucle ahora tiene menos sentido. No está completo. Tampoco tus Ifs, ya que se deberían cerrar con `End if`Deberías añadir un ejemplo visual y el output esperado. [Codename](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.codename) es una propiedad de **solo lectura**. No puedes modificarla, solo leerla, así que la línea `Sheets(n).CodeName.Range("A11") = Inicio.Range("C9")` siempre va a dar error. Además, la variable `n` por tu bucle está devolviendo un objeto `range` pero cuando lo usas en `Sheets(n)` debería ser un integer o un string.

Comment: Gracias @Esei. Finalmente pude hacer funcionar el código y hace lo que necesito. Tu aclaración de que codename es solo lectura me aclaro el panorama. Muchas gracias por tus respuestas. Me ayudaron muchísimo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Dim wk As Worksheet
For Each wk In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    MsgBox wk.CodeName
Next
```

En tu código estabas haciendo un bucle dentro de `Preliminares.Range("A2:A13")`, que es un conjunto de celdas, no de hojas...

Suponiendo que `PReliminares` no sea una hoja sino un Libro, entonces el código que he puesto quedaría algo así:

```
Dim wk As Worksheet
For Each wk In Preliminares.Worksheets
    MsgBox wk.CodeName
Next
```

Comment: Hola Esei. Efectivamente Preliminare es una hoja donde tengo la lista de nombres de las hojas del libro, y de allí leo esos nombres. De todas maneras entiendo lo que mencionas, y trataré de usar tu idea en el código que necesito generar. Muchas gracias!!!

Comment: intenté usar el código pero no tuve un buen resultado. Voy a ser más específico a ver si me puedes guiar: en la hoja Preliminares tengo una lista de opciones (opcion1...). Cada opción tiene una hoja asociada. El usuario tiene que llenar un formulario y elige una opción. Dependiendo de la opción, los datos que completa del formulario se deben ir a la hoja asociada. Quiero indicar eso con la referencia al CodeName. Tengo esto (sigue)

Comment: finalmente edité la pregunta para poder mostrar con más detalle lo que necesito hacer. Ojalá me puedas ayudar con la última línea. Gracias!!!

Comment: @Andres te contesto en tu pregunta principal